# IIS 7.5: Special characters in URL rewrite external file

Tags: web-config, iis-7.5, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have ran into the "max web.config size" for one of my applications running on IIS 7.5, Before editing the registry to increase this value, I tried to move all the rewriteMap rules into an external file but the server gave me back a 500 error.

After several checks I've noticed that this way will work

```
<rewriteMaps>
 <rewriteMap name="OLDSITE">
  <add key="/withonlythis_will_work" value="http://oldsite" />
 </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

But if I put some non standard alphanumeric character it will crash (e.g.) 
old**ò**site

```
<rewriteMaps>
 <rewriteMap name="OLDSITE">
  <add key="/withonlythis_will_not_work" value="http://oldòsite" />
 </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Both rules work if I leave them on the webconfig, but the second one does not work on external rewritemap.config file

any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the HTML named entity for **ò** that is **&ograve ;** (please remove space before ';'):

```
<rewriteMaps>
 <rewriteMap name="OLDSITE">
  <add key="/withonlythis_will_not_work" value="http://old&ograve ;site" />
 </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```